# Taxation systems across countries

Tags: data-request, economics, taxes

Where can I find a dataset describing taxation systems across countries? More specifically:

- How many taxes businesses and individuals pay
- Do individuals pay taxes directly to domestic tax agencies or their employers do that on their behalf (e.g., for income taxes)?
- How often taxpayers fill tax refunds
- Effective and nominal tax rates
- What level of the government gets particular taxes

The World Bank reports [time spent on tax filings](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IC.TAX.DURS) and net tax rates, but not in depth.

Answer (score 3):

This EU documentation shows various Value Added Tax rates for countries in Europe:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf